# How does entity framework count total rows in one query?

Tags: sql, pagination, entity-framework-6

I'm in the process of swapping out some Entity Framework queries for hand-crafted SQL using Dapper. All is going well so far - the only bit I'm struggling with is implementing efficient pagination inside a single DB query.

Our current code is like this:

```
public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    int total = source.Count();
    TotalCount = total;
    TotalPages = total / pageSize;

    if (total % pageSize > 0)
        TotalPages++;

    PageSize = pageSize;
    PageIndex = pageIndex;
    AddRange(source.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
}
```

if I debug over this, I can see the total number of rows coming back from Source.Count().

However when I use Glimpse to check the generated SQL, I can only see one query going off to the database. Something like:

```
SELECT TOP 30 field1, field2
FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2, row_number()
    OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[Score] DESC) AS [row_number] WHERE ..) AS Project1
WHERE project1.row_number > 30
```

I can't see any `COUNT()` expressions inside here, nor are there two queries being issued. I'm really confused - how has it counted the number of rows inside the sub-query?

Answer (score 1):

Your `PagedList` method is actually making two database calls.

1. `int total = source.Count();`
2. `source.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()`

The query you posted would be from `2`

Comment: But how come Glimpse shows every other DB query that EF generates, but not the COUNT one?